# Load staticfies do not work in Django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am new to python Django.

I have a project like this below:

[image]

But in my `TestModel` APP, there is a index.html here:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" /> -->
    <title>Python探索馆 - Slice</title>
    <!-- Main Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />

    <!-- Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://at.alicdn.com/t/font_n5vylbuqe61or.css" />
  </head>
<body>
...
```

You see I have load the static files.

And in my `testdj/` the `settings.py`, I have set the `STATIC_URL`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

---

But in the browser, the stylesheet did not load success.

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

The css structrue:

[image]

Comment: try `{% load static %}` and also provide your settings.py file otherwise I cannot tell you for sure where the error is coming from, because normally you would put your `static` folder inside the application folder and not inside the templates folder

Comment: @N.Ivanov I tried , do not work.

Comment: update your answer with your `settings.py` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put your static files in your template folder. That is not where they go. You need to put them either in your app or in a folder that is referenced by the STATICFILES_DIRS setting.

Comment: I do this, because the tutorial says if I have multi APP here, there is a TestModel directory we can distinct them.